# Windows Experience Index Issue

Tags: windows, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-experience-index

My laptop is [Lenvo ideaPad Z500](http://shop.lenovo.com/fr/fr/laptops/ideapad/z-series/z500/#sp%C3%A9cificationstechniques), it has two graphic cards

- Intel HD
- NVIDIA™ GeForce™ GT 635M DirectX™ 11

The experience index of my computer is `5,1`.

[image]

I think that it's because intel card is set as the default one, however I tried to set the Nvidea one to be the default one via Nvidia control panel:

[image]

The question is : is 5.1 logical with the GT 635M card? and is this the appropriate way t choose the principal card?

Comment: I personally wouldn't care much about that rating, it serves no other information rather than being a very relative way of comparing systems. I assume you're using Windows 7 (from the screenshots); that index might change from OS to OS.

Comment: @HediNaily - You are actually getting 5.1 because you have the GT635M set as the default card.  If you were using the `Intel® HD Graphics 4000` it would be lower.  Of course both have pretty much equal performance.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I'm using Windows 8 x64. Max value is 9,9

Comment: @Ramhound really? I thought that the GT635 deserves more

Comment: @HediNaily - The GT635 is 1 generations old. The `HD Graphics 4000` is pretty much equal footing with at least the 5xx series. There are about 12 cards better then the 635 ( http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, I have the same model, and I'm actually using it write this answer. I just tested by completely disabling the Intel card through the BIOS, and running the Experience Index again. The number did not change.

I'm fairly certain that by default, Windows uses the "best" graphics card you have installed. Changing anything in Nvidia settings won't change the fact the OS can still see the Intel card, but regardless, it uses the Nvidia card to benchmark.

This related [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2461905) provides some insight into WEI.

> For graphics adapters, both DX9 and DX10 assessments can be run now. In Windows Vista, the tests were specific to DX9. To obtain scores in the 6 or 7 range, a graphics adapter must obtain very good performance scores, the adapter must support DX10, and the driver must be at least a WDDM 1.1 driver. For WDDM 1.0 drivers, only the DX9 assessments will be run. Therefore the overall score is capped at 5.9. For multicore processors, both single-threaded and multithreaded scenarios are run. With levels 6 and 7, we intend to indicate that these systems will be rarely CPU bound for typical use and very suitable for demanding processing tasks and for multitasking. As examples, we expect that many quad-core processors will be able to score in the high 6 to low 7 range, and we expect eight-core systems to be able to approach 7.9. This scoring has accounted for the very latest microprocessors available.